# Why the player when he is moving right or left he stuck at place and can't be move anymore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

not sure if it's the colliders problem or the movement problem.

I found now that if I set true the checkbox in the inspector on the pacman object in the Circle Collider 2D component the property Is Trigger , then I can move the pacman around but then there is another problem.  on the Left , Bottom directions the pacman move through the colliders and stay inside the part/s I can then move it to the right and up and it's working fine in the directions right and up but not good with the left and bottom.

screenshot of the pacman when I moved it to the left when the Is Trigger property is set to true enabled:

[image: the property Is Trigger is enabled set to true in the inspector and when moving the pacman left or to the bottom the pacman is not colliding.]

The script is attached to the pacman object iself:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PacmanMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.4f;
    Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        dest = transform.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {// Move closer to Destination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        // Check for Input if not moving
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid(Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid(Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid(-Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid(-Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
        }
    }

    bool valid(Vector2 dir)
    {
        // Cast Line from 'next to Pac-Man' to 'Pac-Man'
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
        return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
}
```

The pacman object settings in the inspector:

[image: the pacman inspector settings]

this is the sprite 2d and ui map with the colliders(colliders are gameobjects):

[image: pacman]

now if for example I press the right arrow key or the left arrow key the pacman move but once he collide the colliders he stop and then I can't move it to any direction anymore.

[image: pacman cant be moving anymore once moved to the left or right.]

screenshot of one of the gameobjects with the collider2d attached settings in the inspector:

[image: collider2d]

This is the script I'm using to automatically adding a collider2d to each wall(part in the maze) :

I can't tell what and where but I think the problem might be with this script.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class AddBoxCollidersToWalls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite wallSprite;
    public float colliderSize = 1.5f; // The size for the BoxCollider2D

    void Start()
    {
        if (wallSprite == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("WallSprite reference not set! Please assign the WallSprite in the Inspector.");
            return;
        }

        AddCollidersToWallTiles();
    }

    private void AddCollidersToWallTiles()
    {
        List<List<Vector2Int>> wallTileRegions = FindWallTileRegions();

        foreach (List<Vector2Int> region in wallTileRegions)
        {
            Vector3 colliderCenter = GetColliderCenter(region);
            Vector2 colliderSize = GetColliderSize(region);

            CreateColliderObject(colliderCenter, colliderSize);
        }
    }

    private List<List<Vector2Int>> FindWallTileRegions()
    {
        List<List<Vector2Int>> wallTileRegions = new List<List<Vector2Int>>();
        Texture2D texture = wallSprite.texture;
        int width = texture.width;
        int height = texture.height;
        Color[] pixels = texture.GetPixels();

        bool[,] visited = new bool[width, height];

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int pixelIndex = y * width + x;

                if (pixels[pixelIndex].a == 0 || visited[x, y]) // Skip transparent pixels or already visited pixels
                    continue;

                List<Vector2Int> region = new List<Vector2Int>();
                FloodFill(x, y, pixels, width, height, ref visited, ref region);
                wallTileRegions.Add(region);
            }
        }

        return wallTileRegions;
    }

    private void FloodFill(int x, int y, Color[] pixels, int width, int height, ref bool[,] visited, ref List<Vector2Int> region)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height || visited[x, y] || pixels[y * width + x].a == 0)
            return;

        visited[x, y] = true;
        region.Add(new Vector2Int(x, y));

        FloodFill(x + 1, y, pixels, width, height, ref visited, ref region);
        FloodFill(x - 1, y, pixels, width, height, ref visited, ref region);
        FloodFill(x, y + 1, pixels, width, height, ref visited, ref region);
        FloodFill(x, y - 1, pixels, width, height, ref visited, ref region);
    }

    private Vector3 GetColliderCenter(List<Vector2Int> region)
    {
        float sumX = 0f;
        float sumY = 0f;

        foreach (Vector2Int tilePosition in region)
        {
            sumX += tilePosition.x;
            sumY += tilePosition.y;
        }

        float centerX = sumX / region.Count;
        float centerY = sumY / region.Count;

        return new Vector3(centerX / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit, centerY / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit, 0f);
    }

    private Vector2 GetColliderSize(List<Vector2Int> region)
    {
        int minX = int.MaxValue;
        int minY = int.MaxValue;
        int maxX = int.MinValue;
        int maxY = int.MinValue;

        foreach (Vector2Int tilePosition in region)
        {
            minX = Mathf.Min(minX, tilePosition.x);
            minY = Mathf.Min(minY, tilePosition.y);
            maxX = Mathf.Max(maxX, tilePosition.x);
            maxY = Mathf.Max(maxY, tilePosition.y);
        }

        float tileSizeX = maxX - minX + 1;
        float tileSizeY = maxY - minY + 1;

        // Calculate the gap between tiles and adjust the size accordingly
        float gapX = Mathf.Max(0f, (tileSizeX - 1) * (1f - colliderSize));
        float gapY = Mathf.Max(0f, (tileSizeY - 1) * (1f - colliderSize));

        return new Vector2((tileSizeX + gapX) / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit, (tileSizeY + gapY) / wallSprite.pixelsPerUnit);
    }

    private void CreateColliderObject(Vector3 center, Vector2 size)
    {
        GameObject colliderObject = new GameObject("WallTileCollider");
        colliderObject.transform.parent = transform;
        colliderObject.transform.localPosition = center;

        BoxCollider2D collider = colliderObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        collider.size = size * colliderSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a trigger collider? When `isTrigger` is on only Collisions Related Functions are called. Like `OnTriggerEnter`, `OnTriggerExit` and `OnTriggerStay`.

Comment: @Obscure021 right I disabled it.  it seems that the problem is with the script that automatically  adding the collider2d's to each "wall" part of the Maze(sprite 2d and ui).  it seems that not all the colliders are in the right positions/aligned.  seems hard to add the colliders automatically.

Comment: Id guess your cast is actually from one side of your player. So testing if you hit something it could be yourself

Comment: @BugFinder I tried to rotate the pacman but same thing happens.  I used a breakpoint and see that after moving the pacman to the right and it hit a collider then when trying to press the left key for example that this line is never true: if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest)  so it's never get inside again.  it is true once because in the start i set the dest to the transform.position.

Comment: I'm trying to make this tutorial: https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-pacman-game just instead editing and adding each collider2d manual to each wall I tried to do it with a script.

Comment: I removed from the script this condition if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest) and in the editor in the rigidbody2d i locked the Z rotation so it will stay 0.  and now it seems to be working.  not 100% i think but working.